# Nested Table in coreData ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nested

I need to set a nested table in core data. For eg, I have MenuList Table in which I have attributes (let's say they are name, id, address, email). So I want to add one attribute which childMenu which is array of custom objects, and again in it I have another attribute called subchildMenu with custom array objects. So I need to save all this data using coredata and manage functions for CRUD.

Below is the code, which I have tries, but stucked at saving childMenu.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension MenuList {

    @NSManaged public var sIcon                 : String?
    @NSManaged public var sId: String?
    @NSManaged public var sName                 : String?
    //@NSManaged public var sChildMenu            : NSSet?


    @nonobjc public class func nsfetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest< MenuList > {
        return NSFetchRequest< MenuList >(entityName: "MenuList")
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Fetch Record
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class func fetchAllRecords() -> [MenuList]? {

        let fetchRequest = MenuList.nsfetchRequest()

        do {
            let arr = try AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return arr
        } catch {
            Logger.error("\(self) - \(error.localizedDescription)")

            return nil
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class func fetchAllRecords(forId: String) -> [MenuList]? {

        let fetchRequest = MenuList.nsfetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sId = %@", forId)

        do {
            let arr = try AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return arr
        } catch {
            Logger.error("\(self) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Save Record
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class func saveRecord(_ tblData: [ListData]) {

        for data in tblData {

            if let tempId = data.id {

                if let arrData = MenuList.fetchAllRecords(forId: tempId),arrData.count > 0 {

                    let tblData = arrData.first!

                    tblData.sId = tempId


                    if let childMenu = data.childMenu,childMenu.count > 0 {
                       // tblData.sChildMenu = NSSet.init(array: childMenu)
                        TblChildMenu.saveRecord(childMenu)
                    }


                    if let name = data.name {
                        tblData.sName = name
                    }


                    do {
                        try AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
                        Logger.log("\(self) Updated Here => =>")
                    } catch {
                        Logger.error("\(self) Update Error Here => \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                } else {

                    let viewContext = AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

                    let tblStatusEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MenuList", in: viewContext)

                    let tblStatusObj = NSManagedObject(entity: tblStatusEntity!, insertInto: viewContext) as! MenuList

                    tblStatusObj.sId = tempId

                    if let childMenu = data.childMenu,childMenu.count > 0 {
                       // tblStatusObj.sChildMenu = NSSet.init(object: childMenu)//NSSet.init(array: childMenu)
                        TblChildMenu.saveRecord(childMenu)
                    }

                    if let name = data.name {
                        tblStatusObj.sName = name
                    }

                    do {
                        try viewContext.save()
                        Logger.log("\(self) Saved Here => =>")
                    } catch {
                        Logger.error("\(self) Save Error Here => \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Delete Record
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class func deleteRecord(forId: String) {

        let fetchRequest = MenuList.nsfetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sId = %@", forId)

        do {

            let arrData = try AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if arrData.count > 0 {
                AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(arrData.first!)
            }

        } catch {
            Logger.error("\(self) Delete = \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "stucked at saving childMenu".

Comment: "array of custom objects", better to create a new entity for those custom objects and have a not-to.many relationship

Comment: @koen I want to create the same table view for childMenu. and access it from tblMenuList. How can I do that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you please describe it in detail?

Comment: @Dimple: please add some more relevant info, for instance, what is `tblMenuList`? Are you asking about how to show a detail tableView?

Comment: @koen I want to add nested tableview in menuList. Like (MenuList => ChildMenu => SubChild) And access this menulist in controller

Comment: @koen Don't make this into an UI issue when it is clearly about persistence of data, it will only make things even more confusing.

Comment: It seems that autocomplete got the best of my comment, I meant that you should create a new entity for your child objects and then create a one-to-many-relationship between your current entity MenuList and this new child entity.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Actually I dont know regarding relationships in coredata. Can you please share relevant blog of it

Comment: It's a basic concept, you should find it in many tutorials and articles so just google for it. It is a knowledge you must have if you want to work with Core Data